# How to Get Id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Get id form this codein javascript/Jquery

```
<div class="star-rating" id="star1">
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="1"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="2"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="3"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="4"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
 <input name="whatever1" id="publicfeedbackvaluestar1"  class="rating-value" 
  value="4" type="hidden">                 
 </div>
 <div class="star-rating" id="star2">
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="1"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="2"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="3"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="4"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
 <input name="whatever2" id="publicfeedbackvaluestar2"  class="rating-value" 
  value="4" type="hidden">                 
 </div>
 <div class="star-rating" id="star3">
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="1"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="2"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="3"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="4"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
 <input name="whatever3" id="publicfeedbackvaluestar3"  class="rating-value" 
  value="4" type="hidden">                 
 </div>
```

How to store clicking rating value in text box ..
my jquery code

```
  $(".star-rating .fa").on('click', function() {
 id=$(this).attr("id");
 $('#publicfeedbackvalue'+id).val($(this).data('rating'));
 return SetRatingStar(id);
 });
```

get id star3 How ?

Please Help me..

Comment: What exactly the problem is? And please provide more info.

Comment: `document.getElementById('star3')`?

Comment: please provide down vote reason

Comment: You have not set `id` of `.fa` elements, So `$(this).attr("id")` will return `undefined`

Comment: `$("#star3')`for jQuery boi

Comment: i need store rating in text box , this is one code this type 3 more rating questions available

Comment: please check now question, i update done

Comment: i'm not sure what your last comment said but you probably got down voted because your question is unclear. It's mostly code and 3 words attempting to ask a question which could mean a myriad of things. If your question is hard to understand it will get downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `id = $(this).parent().attr("id");`

```js
$(".star-rating .fa").on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  var ratingClicked = $(this).data('rating');
  console.log('id: ' + id);
  console.log('rating: ' + ratingClicked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star-rating" id="star1">
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="1">1</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="2">2</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="3">3</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="4">4</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5">5</span>
  <input name="whatever1" id="publicfeedbackvaluestar1" class="rating-value" value="4" type="hidden">
</div>
<div class="star-rating" id="star2">
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="1">1</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="2">2</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="3">3</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="4">4</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5">5</span>
  <input name="whatever2" id="publicfeedbackvaluestar2" class="rating-value" value="4" type="hidden">
</div>
<div class="star-rating" id="star3">
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="1">1</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="2">2</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="3">3</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" data-rating="4">4</span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5">5</span>
  <input name="whatever3" id="publicfeedbackvaluestar3" class="rating-value" value="4" type="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote and accept the answer. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
$(".star-rating .fa").on('click', function() {
    var parentId = $(this).parents('.star-rating').attr('id')

 });
```